# Android exit app instead of suspending

Tags: android, air

I'm developing an Android app packaged with Adobe AIR. When the user presses the back or home buttons, I want the app to completely exit, not just be suspended, is there a way to do this?

On iOS I can add the [`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1) property to the plist file, I suppose I'm looking for the equivalent for the Android Manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

The Activity lifecycle is designed to not allow you to do this.

It is highly recommended that you just finish() your activity and then android OS handles when and if it kills your process.

If nonetheless you need to manually kill your process/application, you can do it like this:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```